# create query for consultation intermediate table cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have an intermediate table that need to get to another table. I explain:

My tables

```
areas (id, name)

organizations (id, name )

users (id, name)

areas_organizations (id, area_id, organization_id)

organizations_users (id, organization_id, user_id)
```

To explain more easily omitted other fields that have no relevance in this case. In a query, I get all organizations_user corresponding to the user who is consulting. Once you have these organizations, I need to do a join to the `areas_organizations` table for the ID of the area, then get it, I need to get the name of each area.

An example of the first query would be like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Organization] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [name] => Lixsys SpA

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Organization] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => MOP Ruta 5 Norte (SCL - Los Vilos)
            )

    )

)
```

I understand very well that I do not write code but with CakePHP, my question is, how do I get the values of `areas_organizations` 1 or more ID returned my first visit.
If it is too complex to understand what I'm trying to please consult me.